# Server 2008 Likes to restart itself

Tags: windows-server-2008

I  have a weird issue here.

I notice about once a week the web server restarts itself. This would be only a minor issue if we were not planning on implementing an IP failover.

I have checked the event logs. I don't see anything that indicates a reason for the restart.

I need some help diagnosing the reason the server restarts. It happened last night at 5:00AM
Last even in the log was 1 hour before the unexpected shutdown.

Here is the Log for the shutdown event. Any help is much appreciated. I know there isn't much to go on yet.

```
    Log Name:      System

Source:        EventLog

Date:          5/5/2010 5:01:12 AM

Event ID:      6008

Task Category: None

Level:         Error

Keywords:      Classic

User:          N/A

Computer:      SERVERNAME

Description:

The previous system shutdown at 4:56:41 AM on 5/5/2010 was unexpected.

Event Xml:

<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">

  <System>

    <Provider Name="EventLog" />

    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">6008</EventID>

    <Level>2</Level>

    <Task>0</Task>

    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>

    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-05-05T09:01:12.000Z" />

    <EventRecordID>346094</EventRecordID>

    <Channel>System</Channel>

    <Computer>SERVERNAME</Computer>

    <Security />

  </System>

  <EventData>

    <Data>4:56:41 AM</Data>

    <Data>5/5/2010</Data>

    <Data>

    </Data>

    <Data>

    </Data>

    <Data>39594</Data>

    <Data>

    </Data>

    <Data>

    </Data>
    <Binary>DA070500030005000400380029008E03DA070500030005000800380029008E033C0000003C000000000
000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000</Binary>

  </EventData>

</Event>
```

Comment: Most crashes are driver problems. Are all your drivers the latest available from the manufacturer?

Comment: Interesting becuase I do get some failed to start errors for HP hardware. Like fans and other stuff. Did not think they were that important.
I can post them If you think it may help.

We have an HP DL380 G6

Comment: it could be a driver issue it could be an ASR- either way the message is telling  you that whatever happend, nobody told windows it was going to happen and no memory dump was created

Comment: Huh....I also have an HP DL380 G6 running ESXi that seems to go through random shutdowns....Haven't been able to trace what the problem is.

Comment: @Holocryptic How long has that been happening for? What applications do you run on it?

Comment: @Campo It's been sporadic for a couple months now.  It's not a regular occurrence, and couldn't rule out power failure (although it's hooked up to a UPS and is in the same data closet as my other server which doesn't have a problem).  It wasn't really a big deal before because we didn't have critical systems on there until recently.  We're running ESXi 4 Update 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found [this](http://forums13.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447627+1273073307115+28353475&threadId=1385861).  Seems it could be hardware/firmware related.

Comment: Excellent! I do not have event ID 57 so I am going to say it is a bad board? I can't seem to find the site that says which batch have issues.

Comment: I upgraded on Saturday all looks good so far! Thanks! How did it go for you?

Comment: @Campo We performed the firmware update, and it still had the problem.  HP came out to replace the MB.  So we'll see what happens next.  Interestingly enough, when we called HP they the techsupport guys weren't aware of the problem.  We had to point them to their own KB.  Funny stuff.

Comment: WEIRD! That sux. We applied and its all fixed! What was your board revision. We were a couple letters past the bad board but the serial number was still too old for the proper firmware.

Answer (score 1):

I FOUND THIS! AHHHH!

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c01955503

Comment: Nice.  Well, off to update I go....

Comment: @Holocryptic When did you buy the machine? Which updates are you going to do? Just ILO and the Logic Device? Or are there others? Are you going to do it online or offline? I am going tonight to check the revision of our board. You should probably do the same if you don't know it offhand.

Comment: It was bought late last year (not sure exactly).  I'm downloading the offline updates (online makes me nervous for some reason).  I'm getting the package from the link you provided, plus the Smart Update Firmware 9 DVD.  I figure I'll make a clean go of it.  I know for fact that my firmware is a little behind, but I will be verifying the revision as well.

Comment: http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=3884083&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3884082&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4040

Comment: Awesome! Yah just check em all and update the ones needed. Did you do the upgrade yet? I am going tonight to check the server.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to HP:
They said to update the firmware and it will resolve the issue. I do not use ILO so I will be running it offline.

[The file and readme are located here.](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib2/software1/pubsw-linux/p1055117448/v59499/)

I was told if this does not fix the problem they will be sending me a new Mother Board.
I really hope this fixes it!

But as of now this is the official solution from HP.