# HP DL380 reboot problems

Tags: linux, hp-proliant

I have recently installed RHEL 5.3 on a HP DL 380 G5.
Then I installed HP's PSP(Proliant Support Pack). 
Since then I cannot reboot the system anymore. The system just stays in "Broadcast message from root (tty0). The system is going for reboot NOW"
Neither halt, poweroff, reboot nor init 6 works.

Comment: The elusive goal of 100% uptime is within your reach!

Comment: Upgrade the firmware; HP has been releasing a ton of updates in the last year (very few of the fixed problems make it into their change logs either).

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to remove the plug from the power supplie(s) for 30 seconds after a firmware upgrade?

We just went through random reboots on our machine [See Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/138831/server-2008-likes-to-restart-itself). I noticed in the instructions for installing firmware you must pull the physical power for 30 seconds. I believe that is only for an offline upgrade though.

After I completed the upgrade I ran into some boot issues. The DL 380 became a lot more picky over boot order. Once I specified boot from hard disk first it booted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I haven't update the firmware...

Comment: Hmm and its a G5 so my issues are completely different. Just thought the HP PSP upgraded some firmware. You say you can get into Red Hat but just not reboot?

Answer (score 0):

HP PSP adds some custom daemons that are monitoring the system.
There are some kernel modules that can be installed (disk array, networking, ...) in PSP but I was happy with the modules delivered by RH.

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort : if you have access to the system console, go to single user mode (init 1), then use the Magic SysRq to force reset. If the system doesn't go into single user mode, stop services one at a time by hand. Something like

```
for SERV in /etc/rc6.d/*
  do $SERV stop
done
```

See which one is blocking. Kill the incumbent manually; or if it's zombified, ignore it altogether.
When most services are down, umount all filesystems, then remount root read-only; then do the sync/reboot magic SysRq.